# How to log X-Forwarded-For in Google Cloud HTTP Loadbalancer logging for export to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, stackdriver

I'm exporting all logs from *Google Cloud HTTP Loadbalancer* to *BigQuery* but I'm missing custom http headers like `X-Forwarded-For` with the origin ip from *Cloudflare*.

I don't see those headers in *Stackdriver* logging either, so it is probably not a problem of the sink export to *BigQuery*.

Where do I enable this logging?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering, how are you sending this data to stackdriver? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Google Cloud HTTP/s Loadbalancer is logging to stackdriver by default. There is no code sample, I didn't code anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the LogEntry is not supporting HTTP Headers.
Based on the [documentation, this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest) is the supported structure.

A workaround can be to collect logs after the Loadbalancer. The Loadbalancer will add the X-Forwarded-for values as a comma separated list to the request.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components